# Solved: Selenium getting stuck at driver.get('URL') for a specific URL

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using
Python 3.8.10
Selenium 4.0.0a6

In the following code, If I try to load 'url2' Google page it can run normally and show the result 'complete'.

but if I change the code to url1, the code stuck at the line driver.get(url1) and didn't run the next line, but i can see the web page was loaded in the Selenium browser.

Does anyone have any idea? Thankyou

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def url_driver():

    chromedriver_path = 'D:\\Programming\\Program\\Python\\chromedriver_2.41\\chromedriver.exe'
    chrome_binary_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
    
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = chrome_binary_path
    
    options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    return driver

if __name__ == '__main__':

    url1 = 'https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/Results.aspx?lang=ch'
    url2 = 'https://www.google.com'

    driver = url_driver()
    driver.get(url1)
    
    print('complete')
```

Comment: Update Python 3.12.1

Comment: try/catch you .get() call and check/include exception shown.  (You may need to wait a while... some browsers/driver will set a long default timeout for pageload.)

Comment: I updated the version of chrome driver and the code works now. Thankyou for helping.